# MVVM: How to avoid ressetting the view content after switching to another view

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, view, viewmodel

I am very new to the MVVM concept and try to set up a WPF application which controls laboratory equipment remotely. After setting up the following views and view models:

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="VirtualLab.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VirtualLab"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:VirtualLab.MVVM.ViewModel"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:VirtualLab.MVVM.Views"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/MenuButtonTheme.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/FuncGenButtonStyles.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/OsziButtonTheme.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:CircuitViewModel}">
                <views:CircuitView/>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:OszilloskopViewModel}">
                <views:OszilloskopView/>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:FunctionGeneratorViewModel}">
                <views:FunctionGeneratorView/>
            </DataTemplate>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
using VirtualLab.Core;
using VirtualLab.MVVM.Model;
using VirtualLab.MVVM.ViewModel;

namespace VirtualLab.MVVM.ViewModel
{
    public class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public SafetyCheck safetyCheck = new SafetyCheck();

        // Commands for Relays 
        public RelayCommands CircuitViewCommand { get; set; }
        public RelayCommands OszilloskopViewCommand { get; set; }
        public RelayCommands FunctionGeneratorCommand { get; set; }


        // All View Models
        public CircuitViewModel CircuitVM { get; set; } 
        public OszilloskopViewModel OszilloskopVM { get; set; }
        public FunctionGeneratorViewModel FunctionGeneratorVM { get; set; }

        // Current View
        public object _currentView;

        public object CurrentView
        {
            get { return _currentView; }
            set 
            { 
                _currentView = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        CircuitViewModel GetCircuitVM()
        {
            return this.CircuitVM;
        }

        // Constructor MainViewModel
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            CircuitVM = new CircuitViewModel();
            OszilloskopVM = new OszilloskopViewModel(this);
            FunctionGeneratorVM = new FunctionGeneratorViewModel(this); 
            
            CurrentView = CircuitVM;
            
            CircuitViewCommand = new RelayCommands(o =>
            {
                CurrentView = CircuitVM;
            });

            OszilloskopViewCommand = new RelayCommands(o =>
            {
                CurrentView = OszilloskopVM;
            });

            FunctionGeneratorCommand = new RelayCommands(o =>
            {
                CurrentView = FunctionGeneratorVM;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using VirtualLab.MVVM.Views;

namespace VirtualLab
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        
        private void minimizeApp(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void closeApp(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void Border_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed )
            {
                DragMove(); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**FunctionGeneratorViewModel.cs**

```
namespace VirtualLab.MVVM.ViewModel
{
    public class FunctionGeneratorViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public Functiongenerator funcGen; // the actual model that contains the functions for the functionGenerator
        public MainViewModel MainVM;   
  

        //A lot of RelayCommands to access the functions for funcGen are implemented here......

        public FunctionGeneratorViewModel(MainViewModel MainVM)
        {
            //Objectdefinition
            this.funcGen = new Functiongenerator(MainVM);
    }
}
```

**FunctionGeneratorView.cs**

```
<UserControl x:Class="VirtualLab.MVVM.Views.FunctionGeneratorView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VirtualLab.MVVM.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="790" d:DesignWidth="1400">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBlock Text="Funktionsgenerator"
                   Foreground="White"
                   FontSize="25"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Margin="20,20,0,20"
                   FontFamily="/Fonts/#Poppins"/>
       
     <!--a lot of  Code for all elements in the view --> 
     
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I encountered the following problem.... every time I navigate between the views, it seems as if the new page is reset, or to put it in other words, the page change causes a reset of the "old" view page.

How can I avoid this behaviour?

Hopefully the given code sufficient information. Otherwise I can provide further code excerpts.

Thanks in advance!:)

Comment: MainViewModel doesn't reset anything. so probably custom views do that (e.g. by setting their own DataContext, which they shouldn't do)

Comment: I don't really understand your code. Can you show your Views and ViewModels (or at least the relevant parts)? Where do your views get instantiated?

Comment: A template is a factory that creates a new view each time.
When you switch a data source, a new view is created for it, and the previous one is thrown into the trash.
To prevent this from happening, view instances must be stored in a collection (usually a dictionary) and returned from the collection when requested again.

Comment: @ewerspej I have now added the code of one of the views and viewmodels as an example. The other one looks basicly the same. I removed the actuall code that has nothing to do with this problem. I think there is no real instatiation, i thought this will happen automaticly when i create the viewModel, that is binded via the dataTemplate

Comment: @EldHasp okay that sounds like this is the problem. I know this is a poor question, but could you give me a small example on how to set up such a collection?

Comment: You are building views for the CurrentView property. Show what you have attached to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the simplest case, you need a similar converter:

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace Core2022.Converters
{
    public class ObjectToUIElementConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object? Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is null)
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            if (!uiElements.TryGetValue(value, out var element))
            {
                if (value is UIElement elm)
                {
                    element = elm;
                }
                else
                {
                    element = new ContentControl()
                    { DataContext = value, Content = value };
                }
                uiElements.Add(value, element);
            }
            return element;
        }

       private readonly ConditionalWeakTable<object, UIElement> uiElements
           = new ConditionalWeakTable<object, UIElement>();

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public static ObjectToUIElementConverter Default { get; } = new ObjectToUIElementConverter();
    }
}
```

Use it in the CurrentView property binding:

```xml
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView, Converter={x:Static vms:ObjectToUIElementConverter.Default}}"/>
```

But I immediately warn you, such a converter is not suitable for all scenarios, it may have memory leaks (when VMs are created dynamically and there are a lot of them), in some cases it is possible to reinitialize remembered UIElements and other problems.

Comment: exact instance of UIElement shouldn't matter. even if new UIElement created from template, it should then restore its state from bindings (provided that view model is the same, and not a new instance; and view uses binding and not some code-behind manipulations which fail to register datacontext change).

Comment: @ASh, My solution is proposed based on how I understood the explanations and the TC code. Its representation is created by Default Data Template. All the necessary values, bindings are set in these templates. Everything works as it should. The only thing to do is save the state of the UI elements created by the templates.
Of course, there are many much more complex tasks where such an implementation will not work.

Comment: I added the converter to the project now (see code below). Unfortunately I get the following errors when I modify the CurrentView property binding

- ObjectToUiElementConverter is not supported in a WPF-Project
- A string with the length Null or 0 is no valid type


 `<ContentControl Grid.Row="1"  
                            Grid.Column="1"  
                            Margin="10"  
                            Content="{Binding CurrentView, Converter={x:Static ObjectToUIElementConverter.Default}}"/>`  

the ObjectToUIElementConverter class is the same as yours.

Comment: @Anysu , You must add the namespace prefix!
Let's say if you didn't change the namespace from my example, then you need to add `xmlns:cnvs="clr-namespace:Core2022.Converters" to Window. Then the usage would be `Converter={x:Static cnvs:ObjectToUIElementConverter.Default}`.
You must add the namespace prefix!
Let's say if you didn't change the namespace from my example, then you need to add `xmlns:cnvs="clr-namespace:Core2022.Converters" to Window. Then the usage would be `Converter={x:Static cnvs:ObjectToUIElementConverter.Default}`.